# Opening a directory with gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This is my code:

```
Program Write_in_folder

Implicit none

Integer::Num_Ber
Integer,parameter::Le=367
Character(Le)::Output
Character(Le),parameter::fmt_1='("Result\Output_",i0,".txt")'
Character(Le),parameter::fmt_2='(2x,i0)'
Character(Le),parameter::fmt_3='mkdir Result'

Write(*,*)"Enter the number:"
Read(*,*)Num_Ber

Write(Output,trim(adjustl(fmt_1)))Num_Ber

Call execute_command_line(trim(adjustl(fmt_3)))

Open(Unit=1,File=trim(adjustl(Output)),Status='Unknown')

     Write(1,trim(adjustl(fmt_2)))Num_Ber

Close(Unit=1,Status='Keep')

Stop
End Program Write_in_folder
```

How to open folder `Result` with `Num_Ber` extension?
For example, if `Num_Ber` is 56 i want to open folder: `Result_56`.
How to check is this folder alredy opened before and if it is i want to stop execution of this subroutine: `Call execute_command_line`?

Comment: Please take care using relevant tags, your question was almost invisible. What does your current program do and what is wrong with it? And please cpnfirm, are ypu opening a file (called a directory by programmers) or a file? You can't open a folder, you can only move your current directory to a folder.

Comment: When program starts I want to open directory with this form: `Result_Num_Ber`.If this folder alredy exist program will jump over `Call execute_command_line(trim(adjustl(fmt_3)))` and in the next step he shall open file in directory with this form:`Output_Num_Ber`.
How to do that?

Comment: There is nothing like open a directory. Such operation simply does not exist. You can open a file.in a directory.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
What you want to do is to change the definition of `fmt_3`

```
Character(Le),parameter::fmt_3='mkdir -p Result'
```

With the option `-p`, `mkdir` will create the directory if it does not exist and does nothing if it exists.

Long answer:

Based on the description of your problem, the intrinsic inquiry function can be used to do what you want to do.
The following statement

```
inquire (file=fileName, exist=existStatus)
```

where `fileName` is a string variable containing the path to your directory and `existStatus` is a logical variable, will return `.true.` in `existStatus` if the directory exists or `.false.` if not.

Coming to opening a directory, I guess you do not mean what you are saying, you don't want to mess around with directories. A directory in a file system is a container and you want to leave the internal of that container to the operating system and use the interface that the system gives to you:

- create a directory;
- list the content of a directory;
- create a file in a directory;
- delete a file from a directory;
- etc.

Now after inquiring for the existence of the directory, you can create it if it does not exists.

```
inquire (file=fileName, exist=existStatus)
if(.not.existStatus)then
    !the code to create the directory here
end if
```

If that is all what you want to achieve, you can use the option `-p` of mkdir. `mkdir -p dirPath` create the directory if it does not exist, and does nothing if the directory exists already.